# localhost- this site can't be reached

Tags: server, localhost, red5

I'm trying to use red5 for a project. I installed it and gave ip as 127.0.0.1 and port 5080. I searched services.msc to start the server but could not find red5. I searched windows explorer and there was  a shortcut to start red5. I clicked it and tried to connect in browser with 127.0.0.1:5080. But still couldn't connect. I searched using netstat and saw that 5080 is not used. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Red5.bat could not find the path to jdk because of the semicolon at the end of the path to jdk in environment variable. I could start the server after I removed the semicolon.

Hope this helps anyone facing the problem.

Comment: A semi-colon on your path or in our script?

Comment: I didn't expect a script issue with our red5.bat, but I was just checking to be sure.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Why am I getting `[WARN] [RTMPConnectionScheduler-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing LCSQM7VOIMTWU, due to long handshake. State: connect`

Comment: @PaulGregoire. I get the initial video red5.flv. It plays for a bit and stops. I check the logs and I get the "closing due to long handshake" . When I go to the localhost/installer I get `NetConnection.connect.closed`.

Comment: Also I get global web.xml was not found. Invalid scope. Scope cannot be null. Scope not added to parent

Comment: Ignore the global web.xml message, its from tomcat (embedded) and doesnt impact the server. Scope null is ROOT and is a special scope that has to be specially enabled, not required for normal ops.

Comment: Long handshake normally means the client or server app aren't responding within 7 seconds.

Comment: Yeah I got that. I'm trying to install oflaDemo and using localhost. Why am I getting it though it's just localhost? The  red5.flv plays for 2 seconds and stops. I check the log and it give handshake too long error. What's causing it.

Comment: The red5.flv is extremely short, probably about 2 seconds; why do you get the long handshake error, I don't know.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Whatever version of red5 I install I get the handshake error. Could there be something wrong with my tomcat? Please help

Comment: I doubt its tomcat, the only thing its serving is http and rtmpt. I always suggest using the latest; go to releases on github and try 1.0.7-M5

Comment: @PaulGregoire. Sorry if I'm annoying you...last question. I installed different versions of the server. Is there a setup.exe file or should I just download the zip and run the server. Also, if I run on one version of the server, should I delete other version so that it can can use the port..I have just been downloading and running the servers.

Comment: @PaulGregoire I added my pc's ip to `webapp.virtualhost` in red5-web.properties of installer and i could install a demo. but i dont think this is the solution..when i try to run the demo, i get the long handshake error again. please reply. at least that you cant help if you cant. im at work and use lan

Comment: Sounds like an IP issue if you had to add yours to the virtualhost param; that parameter should be ok as "*". Try changing your rtmp.host and http.host properties in conf/red5.properties to your IP address and then connect directly to it. The default is 0.0.0.0 which means bind to "any" IP.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but at this point, you may want to start fresh; I suggest trying out pro, which is free for up-to 10 connections https://www.red5pro.com/docs/#quick-start-guides

Comment: @PaulGregoire. um..what exactly do you mean by 10 connections.

Comment: @PaulGregoire. I'm getting an error when i click red5.bat in the pro version. :"could not load or find main class files\red5pro-server-0.3.0.b90-release"

Comment: They have install and setup guides, I suggest reading through them first. By 10 I mean that's their developer license limit; Red5 itself doesn't have a limit.